# Custom metrics in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

I'm running a sequence-to-sequence model in TensorFlow, for which I need to extensively pad my input data (samples' length varies). Thus, any metrics calculated, it is heavily biased (if the true sample is ~10% of the data input to the model, the errors appearing there as somehow hidden by "correct" predictions on the padded part).

Thus, I'd like to calculate "true" metrics (accuracy, AUC or whathever), that takes into account the real sample only. In numpy-ish code, I'd like to do something like that:

```
def adjusted_metrics(y_true,y_pred):
    last_index = np.nonzero(y_true)[-1]   % y is padded with 0 and there is another value at the end of real y
    return AUC(y_true[:last_index], y_pred[:last_index])
```

But, I'm pretty new to tensorflow and:

- I can't do that in tensorflow code. Actually, I'm not able to find the index of the last nonzero element of y_true, when it is a Tensor. I tried casting to numpy using `tensorflow.experimental.numpy` (no effect actually, it still appears as a Tensor?) or calling `.numpy()` on a tensor (not working, despite the fact I don't have eager execution disabled). I tried masking, but it's hard for me to find the mask dimension, also due to the following point:
- All my attempts also seem inappropriate in the context of batches - y_true and y_pred are of shape `(None, max_length)`. I suppose the calculation in batches is governed by my model, but I've no idea how (and if it's possible) to change the metrics calculation to be done per sample, keeping the whole learning process in batches.

Any advice? :)

Comment: What are the  possible values for other nonpaded elements?( negative , float.)

Comment: Only 1s, but there may appear zeros between them that I have to keep. An example of what I'd like to get:
[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]->[1,1,0,1,0,1,1]